# How do I add a weapon sprite to my player on phaser? I want my weapon sprite to be connected to my player sprites body

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, phaserjs

I have a player sprite 'this.player' and a weapon sprite 'this.weapon'. I want to attach the weapon around my characters body. My updated code will be on https://replit.com/@JackF99/test-2d-array#script.js. My current code is pasted below,

```
    const map = getMap();
  //Declare variables at the top of code
  let random;
  //Create phaser settings
  let config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 1000,
    height: 500,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: {
                y: 0
            },
            debug: false
        }
    },
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    }
  };
  //Create phaser game
  const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
  
  function preload() {
    //Preloading assets needed
    this.load.spritesheet("player", "assets/sprites/player.png", {
        frameWidth: 16,
        frameHeight: 30
    });
    this.load.spritesheet("weapon", "assets/sprites/attack.png", {
        frameWidth: 10,
        frameHeight: 22
    });
    this.load.spritesheet("spikes", "assets/sprites/spikes.png", {
        frameWidth: 16,
        frameHeight: 16
    });
  
    this.load.image("floor", "assets/tiles/floor.png");
    this.load.image("floor_1", "assets/tiles/floor_1.png");
    this.load.image("floor_2", "assets/tiles/floor_2.png");
    this.load.image("floor_3", "assets/tiles/floor_3.png");
    this.load.image("floor_4", "assets/tiles/floor_4.png");
    this.load.image("floor_5", "assets/tiles/floor_5.png");
    this.load.image("floor_6", "assets/tiles/floor_6.png");
    this.load.image("floor_7", "assets/tiles/floor_7.png");
  
    this.load.image("wallLeft", "assets/tiles/wallLeft.png");
    this.load.image("wallRight", "assets/tiles/wallRight.png");
    this.load.image("wallBottom", "assets/tiles/wallBottom.png");
    this.load.image("wallTop", "assets/tiles/wallTop.png");
    this.load.image("bg", "assets/tiles/bg.png");
  }
  
  function create() {
    //Spawn player with restrictions
    //Declare Static objects
    this.wall = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
    this.bg = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
    this.floor = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
    this.spikes = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
    //Generate Map
    let mapArr = map.split('.');
    let drawX = 0;
    let drawY = 0;
    mapArr.forEach(row => {
        drawX = 0;
        for (let a = 0; a < row.length; a++) {
            random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (15 - 0) + 1);
            if (row.charAt(a) == 0) {
                this.bg.create(drawX, drawY, "bg");
            } else if (row.charAt(a) == 1) {
                this.floor.create(drawX, drawY, "floor");
          var container = this.add.container(drawX, drawY);
              var sprite0=this.add.sprite(0, 0, "player");
          var sprite1=this.add.sprite(10, 2, "weapon");
          container.add([ sprite0, sprite1 ]);
            this.physics.add.collider(container, this.wall);
            this.cameras.main.startFollow(container);
            } else if (row.charAt(a) == 7) {
                if (random == 1) {
                    this.floor.create(drawX, drawY, "floor_1");
                } else if (random == 2) {
                    this.floor.create(drawX, drawY, "floor_2");
                } else if (random == 3) {
                    this.floor.create(drawX, drawY, "floor_3");
                } else if (random == 4) {
                    this.floor.create(drawX, drawY, "floor_4");
                } else if (random == 5) {
                    this.floor.create(drawX, drawY, "floor_5");
                } else if (random == 6) {
                    this.floor.create(drawX, drawY, "floor_6");
                } else if (random == 7) {
                    this.floor.create(drawX, drawY, "floor_7");
                } else if (random == 8) {
            //this.physics.add.sprite(drawX, drawY, "spikes");
            this.spikes.create(drawX, drawY, "spikes");
                } else {
                    this.floor.create(drawX, drawY, "floor");
                }
            } else if (row.charAt(a) == 8) {
                this.wall.create(drawX, drawY, "wallBottom");
            } else if (row.charAt(a) == 9) {
                this.wall.create(drawX, drawY, "wallTop");
            } else if (row.charAt(a) == 6) {
                this.wall.create(drawX, drawY, "wallRight");
            } else if (row.charAt(a) == 5) {
                this.wall.create(drawX, drawY, "wallLeft");
            } else if (row.charAt(a) == 4) {
                this.floor.create(drawX, drawY, "floor");
            }
            drawX += 16;
        }
        drawY += 16;
    });
    //Generate player above map images
    container.depth=100;
    this.cameras.main.setZoom(2);
    //Create animations
    this.anims.create({
        key: "walk",
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('player', {
            start: 4,
            end: 7,
            first: 4
        }),
        frameRate: 10,
        repeat: -1
    });
    this.anims.create({
        key: "stand",
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('player', {
            start: 0,
            end: 3,
            first: 0
        }),
        frameRate: 1,
        repeat: -1
    });
    this.anims.create({
        key: "attack",
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('weapon', {
            start: 0,
            end: 5,
            first: 0
        }),
        frameRate: 15,
        repeat: 0
    });
    this.anims.create({
        key: "weapon",
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('weapon', {
            start: 6,
            end: 6,
            first: 6
        }),
        frameRate: 1,
        repeat: 1
    });
    this.anims.create({
        key: "spikes",
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('spikes', {
            start: 0,
            end: 3,
            first: 0
        }),
        frameRate: 1,
        repeat: -1
    });
    //Declare Keys used in  game
    this.key_W = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.W);
    this.key_A = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.A);
    this.key_S = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.S);
    this.key_D = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.D);
    this.key_Q = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.Q);
    //Container
    this.spikes.playAnimation('spikes');
  }
  function update() {
    //Apply animations
    //this.spikes.play('spikes');
    //Setting player animations and movement
    if (this.key_A.isDown) {
        this.player.setVelocityX(-200);
      this.attack.setVelocityX(-200);
        this.player.anims.play("walk", true);
        this.player.flipX = true;
      this.attack.flipX = true;
    } else if (this.key_D.isDown) {
        this.player.setVelocityX(200);
      this.attack.setVelocityX(200);
        this.player.anims.play("walk", true);
        this.player.flipX = false;
      this.attack.flipX = false;
    } else if (this.key_W.isDown) {
        this.player.setVelocityY(-200);
      this.attack.setVelocityY(-200);
        this.player.anims.play("walk", true);
    } else if (this.key_S.isDown) {
        this.player.setVelocityY(200);
      this.attack.setVelocityY(200);
        this.player.anims.play("walk", true);
    } else if (this.key_Q.isDown) {
      this.attack.anims.play("attack", true);
      this.player.setVelocityX(0);
      this.attack.setVelocityY(0);
    } else {
        this.player.anims.play("stand", true);
      this.attack.anims.play("sword",true);
        this.player.setVelocityX(0);
        this.player.setVelocityY(0);
      this.attack.setVelocityX(0);
        this.attack.setVelocityY(0);
    }
  }
  //END OF GAME
```

I tried using a container, but the floor is overlapping the character and none of my update function stuff will load. (Could you show me how to use the animations and movement code with container and help me find why it wont work?

```
this.player = this.physics.add.sprite(drawX, drawY, "player");
        this.player.body.setGravityY(0);
        this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.wall);
          this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.attack);
        this.cameras.main.startFollow(this.player);
        this.player.depth=100;

    if (this.key_A.isDown) {
        this.player.setVelocityX(-200);
      this.attack.setVelocityX(-200);
        this.player.anims.play("walk", true);
        this.player.flipX = true;
      this.attack.flipX = true;
      ...
    }
```

I want to implement all of this code with the player in a container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are several things you would have to do:

1. create a **container** add the **player** and the **sword/weapon** *(I would keep the `this.player` and `this.sword` properties, so that I can access them later in the `update` function)*:

   ```
   ...
   else if (row.charAt(a) == 1) {
       this.floor.create(drawX, drawY, "floor");
       // I call the container "cPlayer" to show it is the container
       this.cPlayer = this.add.container(drawX, drawY);
       // like this the player sprite is still accessible
       this.player = this.add.sprite(0, 0, "player");
       // like this the weapon sprite is still accessible
       this.sword = this.add.sprite(10, 2, "weapon");

       // set the size of the container (for the physics body )
       this.cPlayer.setSize(16,16); // I'm Just guessing the size

       this.physics.add.existing(this.cPlayer)

       this.cPlayer.add([ this.player, this.sword ]);
       this.physics.add.collider(this.cPlayer, this.wall);
       this.cameras.main.startFollow(this.cPlayer);
   } 
   ...
   ```
2. Now you can update the `update` function, to move only the container:

   ```
    function update() {

        if (this.key_Q.isDown) {
            this.sword.play("attack", true);
        } else {
            this.sword.play("sword", true)
        }

        if (this.key_A.isDown) {
            this.cPlayer.body.setVelocityX(-200);
            // Flip the Container with the scale function
            this.cPlayer.setScale(-1,1);
            this.player.play("walk", true);
        } else if (this.key_D.isDown) {
            this.cPlayer.body.setVelocityX(200);
            // Flip the Container with the scale function
            this.cPlayer.setScale(1);
            this.player.play("walk", true);
        } else if (this.key_W.isDown) {
            this.cPlayer.body.setVelocityY(-200);
            // Flip the Container with the scale function
            this.cPlayer.setScale(1);
            this.player.play("walk", true);
        } else if (this.key_S.isDown) {
            this.cPlayer.body.setVelocityY(200);
            // Flip the Container with the scale function
            this.cPlayer.setScale(1);
            this.player.play("walk", true);
        } else {
            this.player.play("stand", true);
            this.attack.play("sword", true);
            // Flip the Container with the scale function
            this.cPlayer.setScale(1);
            this.cPlayer.body.setVelocity(0);                
        }
    }
   ```

**Some side notes:**

1. So that the rendering works, with the right *depth* sorting, I would suggest adding this 3 lines at the end of the `create` function. Using the `setDepth` function on a group sets it for all the children. *In your case, if you don't set this, after about *100 tiles* the player would be below the tiles*:

   ```
    this.cPlayer.setDepth(100);
    this.bg.setDepth(1);
    this.floor.setDepth(2);
    this.wall.setDepth(3);
   ```
2. The Container doesn't work **100%** like other GameObjects, as mentioned in the documentation *(first paragraph)*. Check the [documenation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Container.html) if something doesn't work as expected.
3. I would really recommend looking into **Tilemap** of phaser, you can save alot of time and build on functionality that works out-of-the-box. Code checkout [this example with an array](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/tilemap/create-from-array#) or [here is the whole official tilemap collection](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/category/tilemap).

Comment: The movement wont work with the code you wrote. Everything else works great. Specifically this code wont work after I tested it this.cPlayer.setVelocityX(-200);. Ill let you know if I find a fix. Also, thx 4 help and recommendations I will try to use tilemap tonight.

Comment: @JackF99 For the movement you need to use `this.cPlayer.body.setVelocityX(-200)` the **body** part is missing, on all the velocity lines. I couldn't test the code, so sadly I made a mistake. Sorry for that. I updated my answer to me more accurate, I hope I didn't miss anything else. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: when I move left I am able to walk through walls. Do you have any idea why and how to fix that? I just tested and, this.cPlayer.setScale(-1, 1); allows the player to walk through the walls.

Comment: Best way to find this issue is to turn on the physics debug option to see the collision boxes. because of the `setScale` the box might be flipped. just add the `debug` property into the game config and set it to `true`. to see the boxes. you might have to move the container on _flipping_ it.

Comment: Yeah, it works now. I tried to create a tile map but Im not sure why its not working. I created a new post if u dont mind looking at it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76010712/how-to-make-my-2d-array-into-a-map-using-tile-map-phaser. For the tile map im not sure how I would create a collider between the walls and the player, and it just wont show up for me right now.