# How to make my 2D array into a map using tile map. Phaser

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, phaserjs

I am trying to change my code that creates a map from a 2d array through a for loop to 2D array - tile map code. This is my updated code,

```
//DECLARE VARIABLES || DECLARE VARIABLES || DECLARE VARIABLES 
  let random;
  let attackTimer = false;
  //CREATE PHASER SETTINGS
  let config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 1000,
    height: 500,
    zoom: 2,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: {
                y: 0
            },
            debug: true
        }
    },
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    }
  };
  
  //CREATE PHASER GAME
  const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
  
  function preload() {
    //PRELOADING ASSETS || PRELOADING ASSETS || PRELOADING ASSETS
    //SPRITES
    this.load.spritesheet("player", "assets/sprites/player.png", {
        frameWidth: 16,
        frameHeight: 30
    });
    this.load.spritesheet("sword", "assets/sprites/sword.png", {
        frameWidth: 10,
        frameHeight: 22
    });
    this.load.spritesheet("spikes", "assets/sprites/spikes.png", {
        frameWidth: 16,
        frameHeight: 16
    });
    //TILES
    this.load.image("floor", "assets/tiles/floor.png");
    this.load.image("floor_1", "assets/tiles/floor_1.png");
    this.load.image("floor_2", "assets/tiles/floor_2.png");
    this.load.image("floor_3", "assets/tiles/floor_3.png");
    this.load.image("floor_4", "assets/tiles/floor_4.png");
    this.load.image("floor_5", "assets/tiles/floor_5.png");
    this.load.image("floor_6", "assets/tiles/floor_6.png");
    this.load.image("floor_7", "assets/tiles/floor_7.png");
    this.load.image("wallLeft", "assets/tiles/wallLeft.png");
    this.load.image("wallRight", "assets/tiles/wallRight.png");
    this.load.image("wallBottom", "assets/tiles/wallBottom.png");
    this.load.image("wallTop", "assets/tiles/wallTop.png");
    this.load.image("bg", "assets/tiles/bg.png");
    //DECLARE KEYS USED
    this.key_W = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.W);
    this.key_A = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.A);
    this.key_S = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.S);
    this.key_D = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.D);
    this.key_Q = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.Q);
  }
  
  function create() {
    //CREATE ANIMATIONS || CREATE ANIMATIONS || CREATE ANIMATIONS
    //PLAYER ANIMATIONS
    this.anims.create({
        key: "stand",
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('player', {
            start: 0,
            end: 3,
            first: 0
        }),
        frameRate: 1,
        repeat: -1
    });
    this.anims.create({
        key: "walk",
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('player', {
            start: 4,
            end: 7,
            first: 4
        }),
        frameRate: 10,
        repeat: -1
    });
    //WEAPON ANIMATIONS
    this.anims.create({
        key: "sword",
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('sword', {
            start: 6,
            end: 6,
            first: 6
        })
    });
    this.anims.create({
        key: "attack",
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('sword', {
            start: 0,
            end: 5,
            first: 0
        }),
        frameRate: 5,
        repeat: 0
    });
    //GAME OBJECT ANIMATIONS
    this.anims.create({
        key: "spikes",
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('spikes', {
            start: 0,
            end: 3,
            first: 0
        }),
        frameRate: 2,
        repeat: -1
    });
    //DECLARE GROUPS || DECLARE GROUPS || DECLARE GROUPS
    this.wall = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
    this.spikes = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
    //GENERATE MAP || GENERATE MAP || GENERATE MAP
    var level = getMap();
    let map = this.make.tilemap({
        data: level,
        tileWidth: 16,
        tileHeight: 16
    });
    map.addTilesetImage(0, 'bg', 16, 16, 0, 0, 0);
    map.addTilesetImage(1, 'floor', 16, 16, 0, 0, 1);
    map.addTilesetImage(2, 'wallLeft', 16, 16, 0, 0, 2);
    map.addTilesetImage(3, 'wallRight', 16, 16, 0, 0, 3);
    map.addTilesetImage(4, 'wallBottom', 16, 16, 0, 0, 4);
    map.addTilesetImage(5, 'wallTop', 16, 16, 0, 0, 5);
    map.addTilesetImage(6, 'floor_1', 16, 16, 0, 0, 6);
    map.addTilesetImage(7, 'floor_2', 16, 16, 0, 0, 7);
    map.addTilesetImage(8, 'floor_3', 16, 16, 0, 0, 8);
    map.addTilesetImage(9, 'floor_4', 16, 16, 0, 0, 9);
    map.addTilesetImage(10, 'floor_5', 16, 16, 0, 0, 10);
    map.addTilesetImage(11, 'floor_6', 16, 16, 0, 0, 11);
    map.addTilesetImage(12, 'floor_7', 16, 16, 0, 0, 12);
    map.addTilesetImage(13, 'spikes', 16, 16, 0, 0, 13);
    map.addTilesetImage(14, 'floor', 16, 16, 0, 0, 14);
  
    let layer = map.createLayer(0, map.tilesets, 0, 0);
    map.forEachTile(tile => {
        // when spike
        if (tile.index == 13) {
            this.spikes.create(tile.pixelX, tile.pixelY, "spikes")
                .setOrigin(0)
                .setDepth(10);
            console.info(`ASS Sprite at x:${tile.pixelX} y:${tile.pixelY}`);
        }
    });
    this.cPlayer = this.add.container(96, 816);
    this.player = this.add.sprite(0, 0, "player");
    this.sword = this.add.sprite(10, 3, "sword");
    this.cPlayer.setSize(30, 28);
    this.physics.add.existing(this.cPlayer);
    this.cPlayer.add([this.player, this.sword]);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.cPlayer, this.wall);
    this.cameras.main.startFollow(this.cPlayer);
    //FINAL CHANGES || FINAL CHANGES || FINAL CHANGES
    this.spikes.playAnimation('spikes');
    //Set images in layers
    this.bg.setDepth(1);
    this.floor.setDepth(2);
    this.wall.setDepth(3);
    this.cPlayer.setDepth(100);
    this.physics.world.enableBody(this.cPlayer);
  }
  
  function update() {
    //PLAYER MOVEMENT || PLAYER MOVEMENT || PLAYER MOVEMENT
    if (this.key_Q.isDown && attackTimer == false) {
        this.sword.play("attack", true);
    } else {
        this.sword.play("sword", true)
    }
    if (this.key_A.isDown) {
        this.cPlayer.body.setVelocityY(0);
        this.cPlayer.body.setVelocityX(-200);
        this.cPlayer.setScale(-1, 1);
        this.cPlayer.setSize(-32, 28);
        this.player.play("walk", true);
    } else if (this.key_D.isDown) {
        this.cPlayer.body.setVelocityY(0);
        this.cPlayer.body.setVelocityX(200);
        this.cPlayer.setScale(1);
        this.cPlayer.setSize(28, 28);
        this.player.play("walk", true);
    } else if (this.key_W.isDown) {
        this.cPlayer.body.setVelocityX(0);
        this.cPlayer.body.setVelocityY(-200);
        this.player.play("walk", true);
    } else if (this.key_S.isDown) {
        this.cPlayer.body.setVelocityX(0);
        this.cPlayer.body.setVelocityY(200);
        this.player.play("walk", true);
    } else {
        this.player.play("stand", true);
        this.cPlayer.body.setVelocityX(0);
        this.cPlayer.body.setVelocityY(0);
    }
  }
  //END OF GAME
```

I created the tile map but now I have a few issues. Creating a static group for the walls so I can apply player wall colliders. Fixing the hitbox on the spikes sprites (they are a bit off when I turn on debugger). Making the player work (currently he is created, but none of the animations are working. New code can be found at https://replit.com/@JackF99/test-2d-array#script.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have Tiles that need to be layered I would just create one layer. Just create a array with the layout.

It is easier if you have all tiles images in one big images *(most examples use this only one image)*, but if you have one image per tile you can use the `addTilesetImage` function to add each image to the tileset of the map ([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Tilemaps.Tilemap.html#addTilesetImage__anchor)).

***Only if you have one Tile per image:***
The thing you will have to watchout for is the parameters, the most important is the **last parameter** since this will be the number/index-value of your array map

```
// floor 0
map.addTilesetImage(0, 'floor', 10, 10, 0, 0, 0);
// wall 1
map.addTilesetImage(1, 'wall', 10, 10, 0, 0, 1);
...
```

**Short demo:**
*( <strike>the three line commented out are just so that you know how you would have to add the sprite animation, to the tilemap</strike> )*
**Update:** I added a sprite to show how you can add animation to tiles.

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    zoom: 2.5,
    width: 536 * .4,
    height: 183 * .4,
    physics: { default: 'arcade' },
    scene: { create }
}; 

function create () {
    this.add.text(12,10, 'TileMap')
        .setScale(.75)
        .setColor('#000000')
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'})
        .setDepth(100);

     // this is here since loading external images is difficullt in a demo
     create_stuff_for_demo(this);
    
    // 0 is floor
    // 1 is wall
    // 2 is spikes
    let level = [
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], 
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], 
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], 
        [1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,1], 
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,1], 
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], 
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], 
    ];
    
    this.spikes = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
    
    let map = this.make.tilemap({ data: level, tileWidth: 10, tileHeight: 10 });
    
    map.addTilesetImage(0, 'floor', 10, 10, 0, 0, 0);
    map.addTilesetImage(1, 'wall', 10, 10, 0, 0, 1);
    map.addTilesetImage(2, 'spike', 10, 10, 0, 0, 2);
    
    let layer = map.createLayer(0, map.tilesets, 0, 0);
    
    map.forEachTile(tile => {
      // when spike
      if(tile.index == 2){
          this.spikes.create(tile.pixelX, tile.pixelY, "spikes")
            .setOrigin(0)
            .setDepth(10);
          console.info(`ASS Sprite at x:${tile.pixelX} y:${tile.pixelY}`);
      }
    });
    
    this.spikes.setDepth(3);
    this.spikes.playAnimation('spikes');
}

new Phaser.Game(config);

// You can ignore this function, this is done by loading images and sprites
function create_stuff_for_demo(scene){
    // Creating Images and a Sprite for the demo 
    let graphics = scene.make.graphics();
    graphics.fillStyle(0xffffff);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
    graphics.generateTexture('floor', 10, 10);
    
    graphics.fillStyle(0xff0000);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
    graphics.generateTexture('wall', 10, 10);
    
    graphics.fillStyle(0x00ff00);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
    graphics.generateTexture('spike', 10, 10);

    let canvasFrame = scene.textures.createCanvas('dCanvas', 20, 10);
    let ctx = canvasFrame.context;
    
    ctx.fillStyle = "#75FF79";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
    canvasFrame.add(1, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10);
    
    ctx.fillStyle = "#4FAD51";
    ctx.fillRect(10, 0, 10, 10);
    canvasFrame.add(2, 0, 10, 0, 10, 10);
    
    canvasFrame.refresh();

    scene.anims.create({
      key: 'spikes',
      frames: scene.anims.generateFrameNumbers('dCanvas', { start: 1, end: 2 }),
          frameRate: 1.5,
          repeat: -1
    });
    
    let tiles = ['floor', 'wall', 'spike', 'sprite'];
    
    let x = 120;
    let y = 5;
    
    for(let item of tiles){
    
        if(item !== 'sprite' ){
            scene.add.image( x, y, item )
                .setOrigin(0);
        } else {
            scene.add.sprite( x, y, 'spike' )
              .setOrigin(0)
              .play('spikes');
        }
          
        scene.add.text(x + 15, y - 2, item)
            .setScale(.64)
            .setColor('#ffffff')
            .setOrigin(0)
            .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'})
            .setDepth(100);  
            
       y += 15;
    }
    
    return
    
        
    scene.add.image( 120, 20, 'wall' )
        .setOrigin(0)
        
    scene.add.image( 120, 35, 'spike' )
        .setOrigin(0)
        
    scene.add.sprite( 120, 50, 'spike' )
        .setOrigin(0)
        .play('spikes')
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

> You can ignore the function `create_stuff_for_demo`, it is only for the demo, and has some *"crazy"* workarounds.

Comment: I created the tile map but now I have a few issues. Creating a static group for the walls so I can apply player wall colliders. Fixing the hitbox on the spikes sprites (they are a bit off when I turn on debugger). Making the player work (currently he is created, but none of the animations are working. I updated the post with the code and new issues.

Comment: You don't need a static group for `wall` or `floor`or ... . collision on tilemaps are done with `this.map.setCollision(...);` ([check documentation](https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.55.2/focus/Phaser.Tilemaps.Tilemap-setCollision)). Checkout also [this example](https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src/tilemap\collision\simple%20map.js)

Comment: If the game stops working, and error has happed. _(check the browser console, to finde errors and fix them)_ The offset of the hitboxes has to do with the origin. You can see how I fixed it with for the sprite with the call of `setOrigin(0)`, but as mentioned you don't really need them.

Comment: @winner_joiner can we create layers using the 2d arrays ?

Comment: well not directly(as far as I know), you would have to create two maps an place them ofer eachother like briefly mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74257357/1679286)