# How to scale a tiledMap in Phaser3 to occupy the available space in the canvas

Tags: phaser-framework, phaserjs

I want the tiledMap created from Tiled to occupy all the space available in the canvas, the purpose here is to make the game responsive for all screen sizes.

Here is the code for the game, I am working on:

```
const Zombieland = () => {
  const Scene1 = new Phaser.Class({
    Extends: Phaser.Scene,

    initialize:
      function Scene1() {
        Phaser.Scene.call(this, { key: 'Scene_1' });
      },

    preload() {
      this.load.path = 'https://static.hackerkid.org/hackerKid/live/zombieLandAssets/assets/';
      this.load.image('img_3500', 'img_3500.jpg');
      this.load.image('playerDown', 'down.png');
      this.load.image('playerUp', 'up.png');
      this.load.image('playerRight', 'right.png');
      this.load.image('playerLeft', 'left.png');
      this.load.tilemapTiledJSON('map', 'map1.json');
      this.load.image('objects', 'objects.png');
      this.load.image('pond', 'pond.png');
      this.load.image('goal', 'goal.png');
      this.load.audio('theme', 'Four_Under_the_Floor.mp3');
    },

    create() {
      const map = this.make.tilemap({ key: 'map' });
      const tileset1 = map.addTilesetImage('objects', 'objects');
      const tileset2 = map.addTilesetImage('img_3500', 'img_3500');
      const groundLayer = map.createLayer('groundLayer', tileset2, 0, 0);
      map.createLayer('worldLayer_1', tileset1);

      this.player = this.add
        ?.sprite(32, 64, 'playerDown')
        ?.setScale(0.5)
        // ?.setOffset(0, 24)
        ?.setDepth(10);
      this.graphics = this.add.graphics();
      this.obst = this.add.sprite(
        this.sys.game.config.width / 2,
        (64 * 2),
        'pond',
      );
      this.obst.setScale(0.5);
      this.goal = this.add.sprite(
        this.sys.game.config.width - (64 * 2),
        (64 * 3),
        'goal',
      );
      this.goal.setScale(2);
      const camera = this.cameras.main;
      camera?.startFollow(this.player);
      camera?.setBounds(0, 0, map.widthInPixels, map.heightInPixels);

      this.scale.on('resize', this.resize, this);
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const config = {
      type: Phaser.AUTO,
      parent: document.getElementById('phaser-test'),
      pixelArt: true,
      preserveDrawingBuffer: true,
      physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
          gravity: { y: 0 },
          debug: false,
        },
      },
      scene: [Scene1],
      audio: {
        disableWebAudio: true,
      },
      scale: {
        mode: Phaser.Scale.RESIZE,
        parent: 'phaser-test',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
      },
    };

    const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
    console.log(game);
  }, []);

  return <>
    <div id='phaser-test' style={{
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
    }} />
  </>;
};
```

The element with the black background occupying full width and full height of the screen is the canvas.
The `groundLayer` is created using Tiled application and loaded by `Phaser` using `tilemap` method, it has the dimensions of 580x498.
I want the tiledMap to be responsive occupying the full available space of the canvas.

I tried to research and find a solution to this. That's when I came across `groundLayer.resizeWorld()`. But this is not a valid method on `groundLayer`.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A easy/fast solution *(if you knwo the device size will fit the ratio)*, would be to  set the css-size to `style="width:100%;height:100%"` and use the `zoom` property to size the game, in the  config, like this:

**Demo:**

```js
let config = {
    // width of the small game size
    width:  580,
    height: 498,
    //... ,
    scale: {
        parent: 'phaser',
        // calculate zoom with screen width
        zoom:   window.screen.availWidth / 580
    },
};
```

**An Alternative:**
Or ... you could leave everthing as it is, and just zoom the scene in the `create` function, with the phaser camera. Something like this:

```js
class ExampleScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    // ... 
    create(){
        // set the visible area & and ZoomFactor
        this.cameras.main.setBounds(0, 0, 580, 498)
            .setZoom(window.screen.availWidth / 580);
        // ...
    }
    // ... 
}
```

Comment: the 2nd method works, but if I zoom the cameras. I also have to scale other objects right?

Comment: I am searching for a way, where the tiledMap will be responsive for all screen sizes. 
I cannot hardcode the screen size. Am I approaching this problem wrong? Do I need to use a background image for this purpose rather than a tiledMap?

Comment: You don't need to scale the other objects, the camera zooms everything in.

Comment: I just want the map to occupy the full available space in the canvas.
The zoom method zooms in and the character and other objects also get scaled up. 

Like I mentioned, I want to create a responsive game for all screen sizes, how can I achieve this?. A responsive game with 2 layers. one is the ground layer and another one is the boundary. There will be other obstacles also. So the zooming will just zoom in, the obstacles must be re-arranged when we zoom.

Comment: if you have multipe scenes you have to zoom each scene. No rearanging of objects is necessary.

Comment: i dont have multiple scenes, it is a scene. it is a game where we have a hero character there will be some obstacles. The character has to go past those obstacles to reach a destination

Comment: So, just to clear up the solution _(my final notes)_:  If you build everything for the size (580x498 as mentioned in your intinal question) and than zoom the camera, than everthing should work on most devices _(only the device Ration should be more or less the same)_, even collisions and nothing else needs to be. Just try it out, if it doesn't work, post the problems (with code), not hypotheticals. I can't cover all bases without knowing what exactly is the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76010712/how-to-make-my-2d-array-into-a-map-using-tile-map-phaser#:~:text=Just%20create%20a%20array%20with,%28link%20to%20the%20documentation%29

Comment: I saw this answer by you. This actually helps my question.
If I know the screen width and height. I can create the exact number of tiles which can fill the entire available space. 
Can we create layers using 2d arrays?

Comment: Like you see in the attached pictures. I need to create two layers. One is the ground layer
and another is the wallLayer(the border with bushes and logs). Can this be achieved with 2d arrays?